# UpdateOrCreate not working with array fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, e-commerce, cart

here i am having the problem for to use UpdateOrCreate with Array,this is my Controller, here my extra_id is array field

```
 $cart =  Cart::updateOrCreate([
                            'user_id'=> $user_id,
                            'product_id'=>$id,
                            'attribute_id'=>$request->attribute_id,
                            'extra_id' => $request->extra_id,
                            ],
                            ['qty'=>DB::raw('qty + 1')]
                        );
   }
```

here i have used Casts to convert string into an array for that i have done this in my model,

```
protected $casts = [
    'extra_id'=>'array'
];
```

and as of problem if extra_id = [1,2] and again if same data comes up it create new record instead of updating quantity.

Comment: casts also expects attribute passed to be array with keys, maybe re-check if $request->extra_id is array also in database extra id is JSON Object

Comment: $request->extra_id is array and i have stored extra_id as json format in database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`updateOrCreate` method does not support querying using an array assigned to an attribute. It will not do a `whereIn` or, specially, `whereJsonContains` for json fields. It will always take the first element of the array and assign to a `where` condition.

So, in your case as well, the produced query will always assign the first element of the array to the `extra_id` column.

I would suggest to manually check for existence of the object, and then handle update and create separately.

```
$cart = Cart::where(['user_id'=> $user_id,
                        'product_id'=>$id,
                        'attribute_id'=>$request->attribute_id,
                    ])
              ->whereJsonContains('extra_id', $request->extra_id)
              ->first();

if( $cart ) //will be empty if no result
   $cart->update([
                  'qty' => DB::raw('qty + 1') 
                 ]);

else
  $cart = Cart::create(['user_id'=> $user_id,
                        'product_id'=>$id,
                        'attribute_id'=>$request->attribute_id,
                        'extra_id' => $request->extra_id,
                        'qty' => 1
                       ]);
```

Comment: in my case, i have old database tried with the same case, but my json keys with readable keys like ["value1"=>0,"value2"=>0] somehow it worked xD

Comment: Missed addressing json at first, updated to cater for json fields.

Comment: thank you so much you saved lot of my time i was about to implement some lengthy logic thank you, i have never user WherIn before